# Export as tree_data but with extra node attribute

Tags: python, networkx

I have a directed radial tree like so:

```
G.edges(data=True)

`[('data scientist', 'senior consultant', {'frequency': 4}),
 ('data scientist', 'consultant', {'frequency': 11}),
 ('data scientist', 'postdoctoral fellow', {'frequency': 4}),
 ('data scientist', 'senior software developer', {'frequency': 6}),
 ('data scientist', 'project manager', {'frequency': 6}),
 ('data scientist', 'data analyst', {'frequency': 6}),
 ('data scientist', 'developer', {'frequency': 8}),
 ('data scientist', 'rd engineer', {'frequency': 4}),
 ('data scientist', 'research scientist', {'frequency': 4}),
 ('data scientist', 'director of engineering', {'frequency': 4}),
 ('data scientist', 'chief information officer', {'frequency': 4}),
 ('data scientist', 'research assistant', {'frequency': 18}),
 ('data scientist', 'data architect', {'frequency': 10}),
 ('data scientist', 'teaching assistant', {'frequency': 4}),
 ('data scientist', 'software engineer', {'frequency': 6})]`
```

I exported it using this [function](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data.html#networkx.readwrite.json_graph.tree_data):

`data = json_graph.tree_data(G, root='data scientist')`

However this only includes the parent, child relationship and doesn't preserve the extra attribute 'frequency' that I want each node to have. Here's what I want the data to look like:

```
`{'children': [
  {'id': 'senior consultant', 'frequency': 4},
  {'id': 'consultant', 'frequency': 11},
   ...
  {'id': 'software engineer', 'frequency': 6}],
 'id': 'data scientist'}`
```

Note: this is just a sample of a much larger dataset that has many levels of children. I'm currently playing around with the source code [here](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/readwrite/json_graph/tree.html#tree_data) but if anyone has a better solution I'm all ears!